# how to save JSONObject reponse using Shared Preferences in App

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener,
    OnClickListener {

Button login;
Button register;
EditText pass_word;
EditText mail;
TextView loginErrormsg;


private static final String TAG = null;
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    pass_word = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    loginErrormsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnregister);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String email = mail.getText().toString();
            String password = pass_word.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunctions.loginUser(email, password);
            // JSONObject userinfo = json.getJSONObject("user");

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrormsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);


                    if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                        Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                                getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),
                                json_user.getString(KEY_PASSWORD));

                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrormsg
                                .setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

public static void setUserObject(Context c, String userObject, String key) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString(key, userObject);
    editor.commit();
}
public static String getUserObject(Context ctx, String key) {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    String userObject = pref.getString(key, null);
    return userObject;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
 }
```

This is my Server response:

```
{
  "tag":"login",
  "success":1,
  "error":0,
  "user":{
    "email":"sridhar@gmail.com",
    "password":"7a4fb4770d2c404b0c48abd49f4c5f6a",
    "id":"118"
    }
  }
```

Comment: i want to save user 'id' ,response from server using shared preferences

Comment: Do you have issue in parsing JSON or saving to SharedPreferences?

Comment: i m having issues in saving JSON response in sharedPreference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store only id in shared preference from you server responce, you can do it like,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("Your response from server");
JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user");
String id = jsonObject1.getString("id");

SharedPreference sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "sharedPrefName", 0); // 0 for private mode

Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("key_name",id); // key_name is the name through which you can retrieve it later.
editor.commit();


// To retrieve value from shared preference in another activity
 SharedPreference sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            "sharedPrefName", 0); // 0 for private mode
String id = sp.getString("key_name","defaultvalue"); // key_name is the key you have used for store "id" in shared preference. and deafult value can be anything.
```

Default value will be returns if your shared preference dose not have any value for given key, else value stored for key is returns

Comment: Instead of number 0 is better to use defined constant Context.MODE_PRIVATE while providing mode in getSharedPreferences().

Comment: you can put this code in your if condition where you are checking that login is successfully done or not. i.e.  you can insert your code after  `if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                        Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());`

Comment: thank you. how will i come to now whether response id is saved in shared preference or not and how to call saved response id on other activity

Comment: please check my ans i have updated it with code for retrieve value from shared preference

Comment: have add the above code after if condition but log cat is showing me error and i am not diverted to other activity-- org.json.JSONException: Value id of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
01 
org.json.JSON.typeMismatch

Comment: as you don't check the value returns by editor.commit() it is better to replace commit() with apply() which is faster.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you already have the id in the `json_user` object, just do this:

```
String userId = json_user.optString("id");
if(!userId.isEmpty()) {
    getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(YOUR_USER_ID_KEY_NAME, userId).commit();
}
```

Then later to retrieve it, use:

```
String userId = getSharedPreferences(YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(YOUR_USER_ID_KEY_NAME, null);
if(userId != null) {
    //Successfully retrieved user id
}
else {
    //Id not found in preferences
}
```

Comment: what should i write in "YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME"?

Comment: also YOUR_USER_ID_KEY_NAME?

Comment: Like you read it. It's the name you want to address your preferences and the key. But I suggest making a constant (`static final String`) object and then referencing it every time you want to access the preferences and/or key, so you don't escape the possibility of making a typo

Comment: @DarshanJain think as a variable, you need to identify what you safe in the shared preference, so inside the "box" of the Shared preference, will be a variable called <YOUR_PREFERENCE_NAME> (ex:"user_id") associated to the value you pass (ex in your case: 118)